# Which Android emulator supports utilizing connectivity of PC VPN?

Tags: android-emulator, vpn

I want to test an APK. I connect my PC with the company VPN. There are certain URLs that are accessible only when I connect to VPN. The android app which I want to test connects with those URLs. I installed BlueStacks, and in that, I installed APK. But those URLs are not accessible in BlueStacks. Even though the PC is connected fine with VPN. I [found](https://www.reddit.com/r/BlueStacks/comments/rawk4v/how_to_transfer_bluestacks_internet_traffic_to/hnofkpf/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that there is no way to tell Blusestacks to route the traffic over PC VPN. Yet.

Any advice, which emulator I have to use? Which can utilize or route its traffic to PC VPN. Like if I am able to access a website in PC. Same URL should be accessible in the APK running in the emulator as well.

Comment: Hi, note that questions directly asking for app/software recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not putting any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: BlueStacks bases on VirtualBox which installs own virtual network adapter. **This is exactly what you don't want**. Use an Android emulator like the one from Android Studio that does not use VirtualBox or installs an own virtual network adapter.